# Set Monitor DPI in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

On my PC the default DPI is 96dpi, but I want my WPF application to be scaled on 120dpi, is there any way to do that ???

PS: I don't want to change PC settings

Answer (score 1):

why not just make your visuals/text 30% bigger then?